# Access phone without SIM PIN

Tags: sim-card, sim-pin

Sometimes I want to access my phone without unlocking the SIM cards (yes, two of them, so two PINs). It may be that I just want to play some games, and I know that there is no coverage so I do not care about missing calls.

How can I avoid entering the PIN but being able to unlock the phone itself?

Note: removing PIN for normal SIM access is not an option.

Comment: is removing the SIM cards an option?

Comment: No, see comment to Timo Schwarzer's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late for answering this, but I had the same issue:
When you get asked for the SIM PIN, press the power button for some time until the menu with shutdown options pops up. Select "Airplane mode" here. Now you can use your phone without the SIM PIN.

Verified on an old Galaxy S4 mini.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the SIM cards. Then you will not be asked for a PIN. Some phones will show a "No SIM card"-dialog.

Comment: Removing the SIM implies removing the battery, thus losing e.g. clock configuration.

Comment: Ok. There are phones (like mine) where you do not have to remove the battery to eject the SIM card

Comment: Removing the SIM card also requires a sharp tool that I don't carry everywhere. It is ridiculous that I cannot use my mobile phone just because I forgot the second SIM's PIN, which I don't need at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

On my Samsung Galaxy SIII, holding the power button displays a window which can be used to power down the phone. Then the battery can be safely removed, and then also the SIM card. Upon rebooting the phone I get the No-SIM-Card icon in the top-left notifications area, but I can still dial emergency numbers and access the Internet using Wi-Fi. On my phone it is also possible to disable having to enter the PIN from `Settings -> Security`.

Regards.