# How to disable Enter SIM card PIN window under Android 9?

Tags: sim-card, android-versions, dual-sim

[image]

hello see the picture.

I took my smartphone with me and the battery was empty. When I recharged the device I got this typical SIM card message. Enter the PIN.

but unfortunately I didn't know the PIN anymore and couldn't use the device. how can I deactivate it under Android 9? without removing the SIM card from the sim card slot?

Under iOS system I can restart the device. just hold down the POWER button and activate the flight mode. then the "Enter SIM PIN" screen is gone.

Here's a little guide to what happened with me and it's not conveniently solved in Android system:

1. insert one or 2 SIM cards into my Android device. Because not always my PIN notice, I have on the Android device in password manager app. The PIN is stored.
2. go to friends or shop. sometimes it can happen that i am not always at home. and my android device has no more battery and device goes out.
3. when I turn on the Android device
4. the "Enter SIM PIN" screen appears
5. now you don't want to enter SIM PIN or forgot it.
6. unfortunately i can't access my password manager app because the "Enter SIM PIN" screen blocks the android home screen. You get stuck.

in this case I have to go home or ask people if they have a needle so I can remove the SIM card from the device.

I tested with Android 9 and compared it with iOS 10.

Can somebody test if Android 10 fixes it?

I still have a slight reminder that it can deactivate this "Enter SIM PIN" screen in Android 2 via flight mode, just as it can in iOS.

Comment: Eject the SIM card - usually there is no other option. See also https://android.stackexchange.com/q/86413/2241

Answer (score 0):

It depends of your device but usually you can find that settings under:
Settings->Security&Location(or privacy, it depends)->Advanced (this is some times)->Sim card lock->Then sisable Lock Sim card option